# MySQL how to 'group by' by math expression

Tags: mysql, group-by

Here is the question. lets assume that i have table like this

```
id | MF_SONUC   
----------    
1  | 5  
2  | 8  
3  | 15  
4  | 12  
5  | 18  
6  | 3  
7  | 40
```

what i want to achieve is to group by dividing the value by some value(lets take 8).
so the result should be something like this

```
count| step 
----------- 
 3   | 1  
 2   | 2  
 1   | 3  
 1   | 5
```

so far i got this

```
SELECT COUNT(CEILING( MF_SONUC /8 )) AS counter , MF_SONUC
FROM `mytable`
ORDER BY CONVERT( REPLACE( MF_SONUC, ',', '' ) , DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) ) ASC
GROUP BY CEILING( MF_SONUC /8 )
```

here the group clause is raising error. can anyone help me with it?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all your ordering is somewhat wrong: The `ORDER BY` clause has to be after the `GROUP BY` clause.

Second, the calculation inside the `COUNT()` is unnecessary, just drop it.

And last I guess the `CEILING` operation shall also be part of the resultset, so you can reuse it in the `GROUP BY` like shown below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS counter , CEILING( MF_SONUC /8 ) AS `step`
FROM `mytable`
GROUP BY step
ORDER BY CONVERT( REPLACE( MF_SONUC, ',', '' ) , DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) ) ASC
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e008d4/5/0)